# FastText word embedding models based on skip-gram or CBOW

Tags: facebook, word2vec, word-embedding

Can anybody tell whether these [three](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/english-vectors.html) models are based on skip-gram or CBOW methology?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The referenced paper, under those four "English word vectors" downloads, seems to only discuss their techniques with respect to the CBOW model, so it's probably that. (But other vectors from nearby pages, such as those labeled "Wiki word vectors", are clearly described as being skip-gram trained.)

But: once you've decided to trust some off-the-shelf vectors, does it really matter how they were trained? They're either good on your target tasks, or not.